# Can I deploy apps with iOS 8 extensions to devices running iOS 7?

Tags: xcode, ios7, swift, ios8, ios-app-extension

I am creating an iOS app in swift that has a Notification Center widget.

However, I want the app to run on iOS 7 just fine. If I have the widget, can I just run the app on iOS 7 (with the main app, but not the widget working) or do I have to create an iOS 7 version without the widget?

Comment: You can download an iOS 7 simulator and check it out. (Didn't try it myself, but previously you could download iOS 6 simulator with Xcode 5, I suppose you could download iOS 7 simulator in Xcode 6)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can. Quoting [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW3):

> If you link to an embedded framework from your containing app, you can
>   still deploy it to versions of iOS older than 8.0, even though
>   embedded frameworks are not available in those versions.

And this was in the **App Extension Programming Guide**. Therefore, it's only axiomatic that extensions can be deployed with apps to older versions of iOS.

Comment: 1 up for the official link. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work on iOS 7 just fine (if your deployment target is iOS 7 or lower).