# iOS8 Today Widget inside an iOS7 App?

Tags: ios7, ios8, app-store-connect, ios8-today-widget

Given that the current uptake of iOS8 is only 50% I don't want to make my next release exclusive to iOS8.
It would appear from playing with Xcode that one can compile a target, such as the today extension, for iOS8 without changing the main App and leaving it at iOS7.
Has anyone successfully updated an App which is iOS7+ including an iOS8 Today Widget extension?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOS 8 extensions in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25823813/ios-8-extensions-in-ios-7)

Comment: I've got it working in the simulator's just fine. I was more concerned about the review process kicking it out. Thanks for that reference link it gives me confidence to have a go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get my iOS7.0+ App, with an iOS8.0 "Today Extension", past Apple iTunes review and into the store. It works well too.

So to answer my own question, yes you can put an iOS8 Today Widget inside an iOS7 App.

Just make sure you have the correct "Deployment Target" iOS version set under "Targets" for the App and the extension.