# iOS - App extension with higher deployment target

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-extension

While building s Xcode project that supports lower versions of iOS (lower than 8, that do not support App extension) can embed in an App extension to project for users who use recent iOS versions?

Comment: Yes, you can <br>
Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25830737/2122487)